# The difference between using strtok() to inputed string or declared string

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

To understand the behavior of `strtok()` in C ANSI, I worte two code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[101] = "This is";
    char *pch;
    printf("Splitting string %s into tokens : \n",str);
    pch = strtok(str," ");`enter code here`
    while(pch != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n",pch);
        pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The result of This program is

```
Splitting string "This is " into tokens:
This
is
```

Next, I changed it a little bit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[101] = ;
    char *pch;
    scanf("%s",str); //After launch program, I typed "This is "
    str[strcspn(str,"\n")] = '\0'
    printf("Splitting string %s into tokens : \n",str);
    pch = strtok(str," ");`enter code here`
    while(pch != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n",pch);
        pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It prints

```
Splitting string "This" into tokens:
This
```

I can't understand why the second word is gone when I use stdin.

Comment: The second posted code does not compile.  Please correct

Comment: I hope you realize that using the input format specifier '%s'  stops inputting at the first `white space`  I.E. at the space between the words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't with `strtok`, but with your use of `scanf` and the `"%s"` format specifier. That format specifier reads *space delimited* strings, i.e you can not use `"%s"` to read anything with a space in it.

The natural solution is to use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead, which you have already prepared for by "removing the newline" (which `scanf` would not usually read anyway).

It should have been pretty obvious that the `strtok` can't be involved, since you print the input string *before* even calling `strtok`.

Comment: "....   newline which scanf would not usually read anyway" would be better as "....   newline which scanf specifiers not usually save anyway" as `scanf()` does read the newline.

Comment: @chux To be even more precise, `scanf` with `"%s"` would read the newline, but *leave* it in the input buffer.

Comment: Or  `scanf` with `"%s"` reads leading `'\n'` and other whitespace.  Then reads and saves non-white-space,